# How is onclick different from mouseup in case of jquery datatable accordion

Tags: jquery, datatable

I have a jquery datatable with accordion logic to show or hide inner contents. I am disabling the accordion and then trying to click on accordion which does not open the child(inner content). But if click event handler is replaced by mouseup I am able to display row child.

Below is the snippet of accordion logic:

```
$('#example tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var row = table.row( tr );

    if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
        // This row is already open - close it
        $('div.slider', row.child()).slideUp( function () {
            row.child.hide();
            tr.removeClass('shown');
        } );
    }
    else {
        // Open this row
        row.child( format(row.data()), 'no-padding' ).show();
        tr.addClass('shown');

        $('div.slider', row.child()).slideDown();
    }
} );
```

I am disabling the accordions using below code:

```
 $("#example td.details-control").each(function(){
    $(this)[0].disabled=true;
}
);
```

Why does the accordion expand/collapse work with mouseup when it does not with click(which is expected) after accordion is disabled.

Link to jsFiddle: [ClickVSMouseup](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/741426/)

Comment: "*Why does the accordion expand/collapse work with mouseup when it does not with click*" please show the relevant code. How and then do you respond to events for the accordion? The above is standard example code from the documentation, not really related to your question :)

Comment: @davidkonrad I am using the standard example itself. Only disabling the accordion td's on click of a button (Disable Expansion). There is a link to the code which does not work with onClick but does so with mouseup after the button(Disable Expansion) is hit.

Comment: Hey @starhunter, yes yes, but I would love to see your actual code so I can test it myself. Anyway, to make a long story short: I *believe* you are facing DT's namespace. In order to prevent confusion DT add `.dt` to certain common events like `click`. And your child row is certainly under DT rule. So try to see if your accordion event handler will respond to `click.dt` instead of `click`.

Comment: Sorry don't have understanding of DT namespace. However replaced 'click' with 'click.dt' but it did not work.

Comment: You can add a namespace to an event so you are sure you grab it yourself but not every one else by mistake. The fact that your code work on "mouseup" and not by "click" strongly indicate we are talking about that. Can you set a fiddle up with an accordion, just one single row. I believe bootstrap is looking for their own events as well, like `bs.accordion.*` and that is the cause. But cannot be sure. It is by now a theory.

Comment: Single Row Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rakespatni/4tygw693/12/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179488/discussion-between-starhunter-and-davidkonrad).

Comment: You have a problem you not want to describe in detail, thats it

Comment: Apologies if I have missed any details. But I provided the link to the fiddle as asked.

Comment: Yes, a link to standard, no accordions :)